# Is it possible to control time in Siddhi Cep

Tags: java, siddhi

In below example, time is cpu time. What I am struggling is when I run a time series for back test purpose, data would arrive in order but much faster and the subsequent logic basing on the timed window would not be correct
My question:
- Ideal solution for me is to change the Siddi time using timestamp of arriving time series event. Is that possible to do so?
- If not, what's suggestion to fix this issue.

```
from fooStream#window.timeBatch(10 sec)
select count() as count
insert into barStream;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `externalTimeWindow`[1] as previously mentioned. However, what you are looking for is `playback` [2].

In Siddhi, internally there are two `TimestampGenerator`s. Namely `EventTimeBasedMillisTimestampGenerator` and `SystemCurrentTimeMillisTimestampGenerator`. By default `SystemCurrentTimeMillisTimestampGenerator` will be used with the Siddhi CEP engine. But, if you use `playback` annotation, it'll change to `EventTimeBasedMillisTimestampGenerator`. If you use this, Siddhi will use the timestamp of arriving time series event as the CEP engines time.

[1] https://wso2.github.io/siddhi/api/latest/#externaltime-window

[2] https://wso2.github.io/siddhi/documentation/siddhi-4.0/#appplayback

[3] https://github.com/wso2/siddhi/blob/master/modules/siddhi-core/src/test/java/org/wso2/siddhi/core/managment/PlaybackTestCase.java

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you can use the externalTime windows functionality of Siddhi for this.

see documenation
https://wso2.github.io/siddhi/api/latest/#externaltime-window

Comment: This is not to change the whole Siddhi instance time, rather on that specific window. Why I don't vote this answer is because it doesn't address my question.

Comment: @ngontro86 external time window do exactly that. Window will calculate according to external time you send. This won't change whole siddhi instance time. Its for the particular window query only.

Comment: I am asking for a solution to change Siddhi instance time, because given that, all subsequent time-driven logic i.e a separate subscription query to spit out data on another un-related windows every 5sec would work nicely during both "back-test" and real-life. 
That's why I don't vote any answer so far

Answer (score 0):

You can use siddhi externalTimeWindow[1] for your requirement.

For extenrnalTimewindow, you can provide your own timestamp and the window time will be calculated from the timestamp you have provided.

[1] https://wso2.github.io/siddhi/api/latest/#externaltime-window

Comment: Will it set time for that particular Siddhi instance or no? For example what happen to other query to snapshot output every 5 secs?

Comment: The external timestamp you define is for that specific window. You can define more external time windows with different timestamps if you want.

Comment: I knew what you are recommending but i dont feel its nice and right solution for what i am asking.